# PHP and MYSQL select with 5 tables and multiple rows as a single array

Tags: php, mysql, select

Would like to get the following as a result from the table structure below (MYSQL + PHP)

```
array[0][name]1,[desc]red,[title]hero,[desc]strong,[desc2]smells,[img][0]red1,[img][1]red2,[img][2]red3,ext[0].jpg,[ext][1].gif,[ext][2].png,[count][0]253,[count][1]211,[count][2]21,[count][3]121,[dist][0]5,[dist][1]5,[dist][2]12,[dist][3]2,[score][0]2,[score][1]3,[score][2]1,[score][3]5,[score][4]4,[val][0]5,[val][1]1,[val][2]4,[val][3]3,[val][4]4
```

The problem I have with a simple SELECT, JOIN and GROUP_CONCAT is that the values duplicate after selecting all the images.

I've tried various other ways for example selecting the data by row combined with a foreach loop in PHP, but I end up with lots of duplicates, and it looks very messy.

I also though about splitting it into multiple selects instead of using one, but I really would like to know if it can be done with one select.

Could someone help me with an MYSQL select? Thanks

```
game
+-----+----------+
| pid | name     |
+-----+----------+
|   1 |  red     |
|   2 |  green   |
|   3 |  blue    |
+-----+----------+

detail
+-----+------+--------+-------+--------+
|  id | pid  | title  |  desc | desc 2 |
+-----+------+--------+-------+--------+
|   1 |  1   | hero   |strong | smells |
|   2 |  2   | prince |nice   | tall   |
|   3 |  3   | dragon |big    | green  |
+-----+------+--------+-------+--------+

image
+-----+-----+-----+----+
|  id | pid | img |ext |
+-----+-----+-----+----+
|   1 |  1  | red1|.jpg|
|   2 |  1  | red2|.gif|
|   3 |  1  | red3|.png|
+-----+-----+-----+----+

devmap
+-----+-----+-------+------+
|  id | pid | count | dist |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
|   1 |  1  | 253   |  5   |
|   2 |  1  | 211   |  5   |
|   3 |  1  | 21    | 12   |
|   4 |  1  | 121   |  2   |
+-----+-----+-------+------+

stats
+-----+-----+-------+------+
|  id | pid | scrore| val  |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
|   1 |  1  | 2     |  5   |
|   2 |  1  | 3     |  1   |
|   3 |  1  | 1     |  4   |
|   4 |  1  | 5     |  3   |
|   5 |  1  | 4     |  3   |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
```

Comment: cleanup your question, I can hardly read the array part...

Comment: Maybe include the SELECT statement and tidy up that array dump so that it's actually readable?

Comment: Sorry about the messy array. I thought the SELECT code didn't add anything to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do a JOIN that involves more than a 1:1 mapping between tables you're going to have duplicate data, and there's no way to get around that in the query.

You can break it out into multiple selects, or you can loop through the result set and pare out whatever duplicate information you don't want.

Comment: Thanks. I'll stick with multiple selects.